# QnA Maker "Context Only" not working in live Bot or Emulator

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-qna-maker, bot-framework-composer

I'm developing an Azure Bot using Bot Framework Composer.

I've got my QnA knowledgebase set-up with a number of Context-Only questions.

These questions work perfectly when testing in the QnA portal.

I've tested with both my original QnA knowledge base & also the Bot generated knowledge bases.

However when testing via emulator, or working with the Bot in a live environment it bypasses the Context-Only element entirely.

I need the Context-Only elements to work as we have a number of identical departments in different locations - so the same question will require a different answer depending on where our users are based.

Not sure what more info to provide, but if anyone has any insight I'd gratefully welcome it.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced the thread and tested it in QnA emulator and web chat. In both cases it worked for and got a response from the bot.

Go to https://language.azure.com/

[image]

Choose the Custom question answering

[image]

Choose Custom question answering

Click on “**Open custom question answering**”

[image]

Click on “**Create new project**”

[image]

[image]

Click on “**Edit knowledge base**”

[image]

Click on **Add questions pair**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Tested in Studio. Worked well

[image]

Click on “**Deploy knowledge base**”

[image]

Click on create a bot.

[image]

[image]

Create a bot

[image]

Go to “**Test in web chat**”. Test there. It worked for me.

We can create synonyms as the context-based elements. When we have context-based, the model can be trained for short form questions, instead of complete pattern of the question.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. Sadly at this moment in time unable to use the new Language Studio as it hasn't been integrated into Bot Framework Composer - this will still only reference QnA resources (see https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/issues/9133)

As soon as we can I'll move over to Language Studio.

Comment: Language studio was integrated with Bot framework. As I reproduced, step by step. It functioned for me perfectly.

Comment: Bot Framework Composer is an IDE built on the Bot Framework SDK. It's a visual designer/no-code, low-code tool.

It doesn't yet have integration with Language Studio. Adding any QnA knowledgebases only links with QnA resources in Azure - not Language Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve this by adding my Bot to Bot Emulator, and adding the QnA knowledgebase as a service.

This allowed me to trace the QnA pairs, publish & train within emulator & drive the questions down the correct Context-Only route.